# Creating a read only table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where I need to provide read only access to a role on a specific table.

Provided Grant Select on Table to Role priviledge.

User using the role is able to view the data but how i can restrict the user from performing CTAS and recreating that table data in some other database where he might have create priviledge.

Ex scenario,

RestrictedDB.RestrictedSch.Table1
Provide Select on above to Role.

How to restrict User using the role to perform below

`Create table unrestrictedDB.public.Table1Copy as select * from RestrictedDB.RestrictedSch.Table1`

Answer (score 0):

If a user has the privileges to read data in one location and write data in another location then there is no way to prevent them writing the data to that location.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Nick, there is no direct solution for this. If a user has SELECT privileges to select from a table, the user is always allowed to take this data and store it in another database (as long has he has privileges to CREATE/INSERT there).

To find a workaround, I first thought about a stored procedure with owner rights then. With this you could create a procedure, which is providing the data to the end user although he has no SELECT privileges on the table: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html

Unfortunately this is still not doing the trick, because the end user could still use RESULT_SCAN to grab the output and take it forward: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html

Comment: Yes I also figured the same. I suppose the only way is to create a standalone role having Select access on the table and assigning that role to the user. The user supposedly should be able to view the data only using the standalone role and not able to move it around

Comment: Yes. This would be fine.